# wrong type specifier returning address value in java

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int[] iray ={1,2,3,4};
    char[] cray ={'b','u','c','y'};

    printMe(iray);
    System.out.println();
    printMe(cray);

}
public static void printMe(int[] a)
{
    for(int x: a)
        System.out.printf("%s", a);
}
public static void printMe(char[] a)
{
    for(char x: a)
        System.out.printf("%s", a);
}
```

}

This returns output as : 
[I@15db9742[I@15db9742[I@15db9742[I@15db9742
[C@6d06d69c[C@6d06d69c[C@6d06d69c[C@6d06d69c

Why is the answer returning address values. However, when I replace a in print statement with x initialized in advance for loop, it returns correct value ie

1234
bucy

Why is that so?

Comment: ... Because this is what `array.toString()` yields in Java. Which is why there is [`Arrays.deepToString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object[])).

Comment: See the enhanced for loop part of https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the answer returning address values. However, when I replace a in print statement with x initialized in advance for loop, it returns correct value ie
>
> 1234 bucy
>
> Why is that so?

`a` is an array object. That is why you seeing address.

To print an array properly as you said iterate over it or use `Arrays.toString(a)`

Comment: @ANC : If "a" is an array object, when we use advance loop : For(int x: a) , we can say that to be "int x = a" , can't we say "x" is also an object. If that is true then why am I getting correct answer when placing "x" instead of "a". Moreover, won't we call "a" & "x" as reference variables referring to an object rather than objects themselves?

Answer (score 1):

You are **printing array object which prints the hashcode**, so simply print the loop variable like below:

```
for(int x: a)
    System.out.printf("%s", x);


for(char x: a)
     System.out.printf("%s", a);
```

Comment: OP already knows this :) Read his last lines of question

Comment: thanks, just highlighted the section to address his question on why?